# Prove $\lim\frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Prove $\lim\frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n}=0$

Using the fact that $\left|s_n-s\right|\lt \epsilon$

I'm finding it difficult to solve for $n$.  I recognize the function is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, but I don't know how to use this information to help with my proof.

I was able to get it into the below form:

$\sin(n^2)\lt \frac{3n\epsilon}{4}$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is the limit at $0$, or $\infty$? Given the choice of letter $n$, it looks like it is $n\to\infty$ (and $n$ integer), but you may want to make that explicit.

Comment: @ClementC. the problem doesn't specify, I copied exactly as written

Comment: What you have to realize here is that $\lvert \sin(n^2) \rvert \leq 1$ while $\lvert n \rvert$ just keeps growing and growing.

Comment: Without knowing where n is going there can be no answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the limit is $n \to \infty$, so we want to show that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that:
$$n > N \implies \left\lvert \frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n} \right\rvert < \epsilon$$

Again, we're given $\epsilon$ and we want to find $N$. I think you were doing something like this, but I just want to clarify.

Now, we can do the following with this expression:
$$\left\lvert \frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n} \right\rvert=\frac{\left\lvert 4\sin(n^2)\right\rvert}{\left\lvert 3n\right\rvert}=\frac{4\lvert\sin(n^2)\rvert}{3\lvert n\rvert}$$
We know that $\lvert\sin(n^2)\rvert \leq 1$ and since $n \to \infty$, we can assume $n > 0$ so $\lvert n \rvert=n$, so we get:
$$\left\lvert \frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n} \right\rvert=\frac{4\lvert\sin(n^2)\rvert}{3\lvert n\rvert} \leq \frac{4}{3n} < \epsilon$$
Solving for $n$, we get $n > \frac{4}{3\epsilon}$. Thus, if we are given $\epsilon$, we can choose $N=\frac{4}{3\epsilon}$ to satisfy the original conditional at the top, concluding the proof.

Comment: I think I understand.  So you were able to simplify the numerator because the function is bounded and approaching $1$?

Comment: @free_mind The numerator is not approaching anything. I was able to simplify the numerator only because it was bounded.

Comment: But if $\sin(n^2)$  has an upper bound of $1$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ isn't that essentially saying $\sin(n^2)$ is $1$?  I think we are saying the same thing but I just want to understand why what I'm saying doesn't make sense haha

Comment: Here is [a graph of $y=\sin(x^2)$ from Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsin(x%5E2)). Look at how it keeps alternating between $1$ and $-1$. As $n \to \infty$, it will just keep alternating between $1$ and $-1$. It will never mellow out and settle on a limit of $1$: It will just keep changing between those values. This is how the function is bounded without having a limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For any real number $t$ we have $-1\leq \sin t\leq 1$. Now, given $\varepsilon>0$ take $n>\frac{4}{3\varepsilon}$, so $$-\frac{4}{3\left(\frac{4}{3\varepsilon}\right)}<-\frac{4}{3n}\leq \frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n}\le\frac{4}{3n}<\frac{4}{3\left(\frac{4}{3\varepsilon}\right)} \qquad\implies\qquad -\varepsilon<\frac{4\sin(n^2)}{3n}<\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

Well: $|sin(n^2)|\leq1$
So:
$|\frac{sin(n^2)}{n}|\leq \frac{1}{n}$

Hopefully you can finish from here.

Comment: I'm new to proving limits, can you elaborate a little as to where you got the $1$ and how you came up with the second equation?

Answer (score 1):

I am opting to use Squeeze theorem.

It is known that

$-1 \le \sin({n^2}) \le 1$

$\rightarrow -\frac{4}{3n} \le \frac{4\sin({n^2})}{3n} \le \frac{4}{3n}$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-\frac{4}{3n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{4}{3n})=0$

$\rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{4\sin({n^2})}{3n}=0$ (By squeeze theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Use the squeeze theorem: 4/(3n) goes to 0 and so does -4/(3n). Our function is between these functions (in value at each point) so it goes to 0.